# It crashes because the variable is null, while checking if it is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

So I have this line in a C# MVC View:

```
<li class="header">@( account != null ? account.Name : "" )</li>
```

Every once in a while it crashes with this exception:

> System.NullReferenceException. account was null

What gives?

Comment: are you sure exception comes at this line?

Comment: Do you change `account` in other thread?

Comment: Yes, I would have taken a screenshot of it and attach it to the ticket, but I don't know how. The funny thing is that it does not happen all the time.

Comment: Sinatr, nope, this view is the result of logging successfully, so account has a value, it was just set

Comment: Adding screenshot [is easy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/299295).

Comment: Can we see the stack trace?

Comment: Cool, I didn't know

Comment: This probably isn't the code throwing, but either way you should switch it to use `account?.Name ?? ""` you might not even need the null colesance

Comment: I'll add the stack trace and the screenshot as soon as it happens again. As I said, it is intermittent (don;t you love it when you have an intermittent bug?)

Comment: @johnny5: That was the first thing I try, but because the production server has not been updated, I have to use C# 5, and C# 5 does not have the ?. or the ?? operators.

Comment: C# 5 has the ?? operator, but I would look at all the other references to account